# Formatted micro SDHC card but partitions and files remain

Tags: partition, sd-card

I have 2 Samsung EVO micro SDHC cards that I was using in a Raspberry Pi. I'm now trying to format them on my Macbook Air running Big Sur on Apple Silicon and have tried two methods for formatting, and they ran without errors but the files and partitions remain:

1 - SD Card Formatter - tried both quick format and overwrite format

2 - `sudo diskutil partitionDisk /dev/diskN 1 MBR "Free Space" "%noformat%" 100%` (`diskN` replaced with `disk4` in my case)

Does anyone have any suggestions? I'm hoping I don't have to throw them out and order new ones.

Edit:
I've tried `diskutil erasedisk fat32 NONE mbr /dev/disk4` and also with
`sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=33 of=/dev/disk4` first, and this results in the following:

```
Started erase on disk4
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk4s1 as MS-DOS (FAT32) with name NONE
Error: -69830: This operation requires an unmounted disk
```

Here are some other outputs

```
diskutil list disk4
/dev/disk4 (external, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *16.0 GB    disk4
   1:             Windows_FAT_16 ⁨RECOVERY⁩                1.2 GB     disk4s1
   2:                      Linux ⁨⁩                        33.6 MB    disk4s5
   3:             Windows_FAT_32 ⁨boot⁩                    72.4 MB    disk4s6
   4:                      Linux ⁨⁩                        14.7 GB    disk4s7
```

```
sudo fdisk /dev/disk4
Disk: /dev/disk4    geometry: 1947/255/63 [31291392 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0E  128   0   1 - 1023   3  16 [      8192 -    2362902] DOS FAT-16
 2: 05 1023   3  16 - 1023   3  16 [   2371094 -   28920298] Extended DOS
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 83 1023   3  16 - 1023   3  16 [   2375680 -      65534] Linux files*
 2: 05 1023   3  16 - 1023   3  16 [   2441214 -   28850178] Extended DOS
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 0C 1023   3  16 - 1023   3  16 [   2441216 -     141312] Win95 FAT32L
 2: 05 1023   3  16 - 1023   3  16 [   2582528 -   28708864] Extended DOS
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: 83 1023   3  16 - 1023   3  16 [   2588672 -   28702720] Linux files*
 2: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 3: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
 4: 00    0   0   0 -    0   0   0 [         0 -          0] unused
```

```
sudo gpt -r show /dev/disk4                                                                                     
     start      size  index  contents
         0         1         MBR
         1      8191
      8192   2362902      1  MBR part 14
   2371094  28920298      2  MBR part 5
```

```
$ echo "auto dos\nq\ny" | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk4                                    
Password:
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
Enter 'help' for information
fdisk: 1> fdisk:*1> Writing current MBR to disk.
Device could not be accessed exclusively.
A reboot will be needed for changes to take effect. OK? [n] %
------------------------------------------------------------
$ sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -v MYSDCARD /dev/disk4s1                                     
newfs_msdos: /dev/disk4s1: Resource busy
------------------------------------------------------------
$ diskutil mount disk4s1                                                              
Volume RECOVERY on disk4s1 mounted
```

```
$ echo "erase\nq\ny" | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk4                                       
fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory
Enter 'help' for information
fdisk: 1> fdisk:*1> Writing current MBR to disk.
Device could not be accessed exclusively.
A reboot will be needed for changes to take effect. OK? [n] %
```

Comment: Try `diskutil erasedisk fat32 NONE mbr disk3`

Comment: I tried that but am getting the following error: `Started erase on disk4
Unmounting disk
Creating the partition map
Waiting for partitions to activate
Formatting disk4s1 as MS-DOS (FAT32) with name NONE
Error: -69830: This operation requires an unmounted disk`

Comment: You could try first zeroing out the partition tables at the beginning of the drives: `sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=33 of=/dev/disk4`

Comment: You could also try posting the output from the commands `diskutil list disk4`, `sudo fdisk /dev/disk4` and `gpt -r show /dev/disk4`. These commands do not change anything, but would give a better idea of what is inside.

Comment: I've tried `sudo dd if=/dev/zero count=33 of=/dev/disk4` with the same result. I've also included the outputs from those three commands

Answer (score 1):

Big Sur (macOS 11.1) seams to have problems dealing the `FDisk_partition_scheme` when the `Extended DOS` partition is not the 4th entry in the Master Boot Record (MBR) partition table.

The OP tried to use various forms of the `diskutil` command to erase the current partitioning. Also, the OP tried using the `dd` command to overwrite the MBR table with zeros. Both `diskutil` and `dd` commands require exclusive access to `disk4` before making changes. Evidently, this fails to happen.

The `fdisk` command will work with shared access. One possible solution would be to use the following to erase all the partitions.

```
echo "erase\nq\ny" | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk4
```

Another possible solution would be to use the following to create a single FAT32 formatted volume.

```
echo "auto dos\nq\ny" | sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk4
sudo newfs_msdos -F 32 -v MYSDCARD /dev/disk4s1
diskutil mount disk4s1
```

> Note: I have observed the `mountdisk` verb of `diskutil` command does not always mount all mountable and UI-browsable volumes on the given partition map.

Comment: Thanks for much for the suggestions. I tried running `sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk4` and got the result, `fdisk: could not open MBR file /usr/standalone/i386/boot0: No such file or directory`. FWIW the other SD card had a single partition and I was able to format it with a Raspberry Pi Imager program on my MBA. I also have a windows 10 machine sitting around, so I plan to give that a shot.

Comment: No version of macOS (OS X) has the `boot0` file. The message is just a warning and can be ignored. The file is not needed. I should also point out entering the command `sudo fdisk -e /dev/disk4` alone will not do anything. You need to enter the entire line posted in my answer.

Comment: I did try the entire lines as posted, and pasted the outputs above. Based on the output, it sounds like they aren't working because the resource is being shared.

Comment: It looks the same as what I pasted

Comment: From new output posted to your question, I can see the commands are not changing the MBR partition table.  @Tetsujin had posted a comment which has now been deleted. I believe the opinion was the card is bad and may need to be replaced. You may want to first try erasing using a machine running Windows. You have now tried everything that I know of that macOS has to offer.

Comment: Thank you for all the help. I tried on a windows machine, but I don't have the rights to run diskpart on it. Good to know that we've tried pretty much everything. I'll just replace and get a 3-pack since another one of these went bad on me not too long ago as well.